# Excel - Count cells according to occurrence

Tags: excel

In the above eg- it should show the count value - 8

Answer (score 1):

This requires an array formula. To enter an array formula, enter the formula into a cell and then hit `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.

```
=SUM(IF(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1:C5,ROW(A1:C5)-1,0,1,3),"<>""")>0,1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Put this formula in D1:

   ```
   =IF(COUNT(A1:C1)>0,1,0)
   ```
2. Copy the formula down for as many rows as you have.
3. Take the sum of column D.

Comment: Do you know in advance how many rows and columns you're going to have?